# Zero divisors and polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the following question:

If $c \in R$ is a zero divisor in a commutative ring $R$, then $c$ is also a zero divisor in $R[x]$

I think the answer is yes. However, I am not sure if my interpretation of what it means for $c$ to be a zero divisor of $R[x]$ is correct.

We defined a polynomial as $\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}x^{i}\in R[x]$  If  $c$ is a zero divisor in $R$ then
there exist a polynomial $f=\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}x^{i} \in R[x]$, and $cf = c \sum_{i=0}^{k}a_{i}x^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} ca_{i}x^{i}$   If $ca_{i} = 0$ and $a_{i}\neq 0$ for $i = 0,...k$ then $f\neq 0$.  Also $c \neq 0$ with $cf=0$ makes $c$ a zero divisor in $R[x]$

I try to phrase it in such a way where it includes only the case where $f$ is the constant polynomial or a polynomial of up to degree $k$ with some or all of the coefficients not equal to zero.  I am not sure if my wordings reflects what I intend to say.  Thank you in advance

Comment: This looks fine! I think you don't need to worry about the case where $f$ is constant, since you already know that there exists some $a_0$ where $a_0\ne0$ and $a_0c=0,$ so this is captured as a constant in $R[x]$ as $0x^k + \cdots + 0x+a_0$

Comment: @Chickenmancer thank you for checking it over for me.  I know there has been quite a few posts about the converse.  I got the question from Hungerford's intro to abstract algebra text. I still am not sure what the word "indeterminate" mean when it refers to $x$ as a place holder.   Because of that it took me a long time to try to figure out whether  the value of the polynomial evaluated at $x$ that counts or whether the value of the polynomial $f$ determine by the coefficients that matters.

Comment: Formally, the term $x$ isn't actually representing a possible value, as it does with a polynomial function. There isn't anything wrong with thinking about $x$ as a variable, but calling it an indeterminate form is the same as calling it a variable. It depends on the viewpoint one wishes to take. So, to answer your question, I think what matters in this context are the coefficients only. Assuming I understood your question properly.

Comment: @Chickenmacer ok I understand now. Thank you for your explanation.